# How to solve JSON response could not be parsed issue?

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

It seems to be very critical issue, I have googled a lot about it but I didn't get the solution.

I am using:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse response, NSData jsonData, NSError *error)
```

This is what I am using to parse JSON data:

```
NSDictionary *jsonResponse =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

and this is what I am getting:

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow
>   fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x16dd0320 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text
>   did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not
>   set.

any help will be appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Log that: `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` check in a JSON Validator (there are plenty online) if it's valid JSON or not.

Comment: Most likely this happens because the data you received is not JSON. Do NOT use NSJSONReadingAllowFragments unless you expect fragments (and I have never seen anyone expecting fragments); it's not going to fix your problem if you expected an array or dictionary.

Comment: It is showing invalid JSON in JSON Validator

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue in Objective-c.
Use this snippet in your request-

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Happy coding ;)

Comment: Beside the fact, that it has nothing to do with Objective-C. ;-) It is Cocoa and HTTP.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I heard that there is an issue on "HTTPHeaderField" in request parameter. But thank you for updating me :)